# Unable to use json array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns the following coming from rest call

```
[{"ProjectId":"CMS","EmpId":3405,"user":"xxx"}]
```

which Iam storing in a variable empdata.Now I want to use that json object in that array .Every time the length would be 1.Iam trying to console empdata[0] it is giving me [ .How can I capture that json object so that I can use

Comment: Are you sure that it is JSON and not a javascript array ? What error do you have ?

Comment: post your code for the better understanding

Comment: You can try using `JSON.parse( empdata )[0]`

Comment: maybe this help: `var parsedData = JSON.parse('[{"ProjectId":"CMS","EmpId":3405,"user":"xxx"}]')[0]; console.log(parsedData.user);`

Comment: Use this angular.fromJson("your json");

Comment: The fact that `[0]` returns `"["` is clear proof that it's still a string. You need to parse your JSON string into an object with `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to parse the rest answer before using it ?

**var obj= JSON.parse(responseText);

var ProjectId=obj.ProjectId;

var EmpId=obj.EmpId;

var user=obj.user;**